# What is the purpose of a capacitor in the feedback path of a unity gain buffer?

Tags: capacitor, operational-amplifier

[image]

First time using this site, I'm an EE student and have been studying opamps. So far in class we have only discussed 'ideal' opamps, but I saw an opamp with this layout and was wondering if anyone could clarify what 'C1' and 'R1' are used for?

I have been trying to look for answers online, and believe I have a good understanding of what 'R1' is doing, but I have been unable to find any answers for what 'C1' is accomplishing.

This is not a assignment, just my own curiosity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

R1 and R2 being equal (R) means that the offset error due to input bias current (but not input offset current) is eliminated. If an equal current Ib flows out of each input pin then each pin will be higher by Ib * R and if the impedance at V_in is much lower than R, the two cancel out.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3ND2I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The capacitor (if chosen to be large enough) reduces to a neglible value the phase shift in the feedback due to input capacitance of the op-amp (with R) that could reduce the phase margin and potentially cause instability. So it eliminates a problem that is caused by using R in the feedback rather than a short.

Comment: The LT1002 offers separate inputs for bias compensation; is there any particular reason adding the resistors and capacitors shown would be better than using the bias-compensation feature?

Comment: @supercat The null inputs are for nulling the input offset voltage, not for errors due to the input bias current. The input bias current is temperature sensitive so attempting to null offset due to bias current by using the offset voltage null terminals would degrade the temperature stability (and it could run out of range). Trimming to a non-zero offset voltage (to compensate for the real input voltage due to bias current) also degrades temperature stability by the factor (Vos/300)uV/°C.

Comment: So am I understanding right to say that the value of 'R1' needs to be the same as the total Resistance seen by the other input (in this case 'R2') and the value of 'C1' needs to be the capactiance of the internal capactiance between the two inputs plus the capactiance of the input to ground? so no matter what the size of resistor for the LT1002 the value of 'C1' will always be the same?

Comment: Also, just so you know LT1002 was just an opamp I chose at random when I was making this circuit in LTspice, I am just trying to get an understanding of this layout, not necessarily with this particular opamp. And thank you for your help.

Comment: @Dragon4th Yes to the question on R1 (DC path resistance should be matched). The value of C1 should be much bigger than the capacitance to ground, not the same. You might use 0.1uF or something like that if R is not too big.